# Javascript issue with Django Debug toolbar

Tags: javascript, django, django-debug-toolbar

I am currently building an application with Django and using the **Django Debug Toolbar** to optimize it.

When I run my application (with `DEBUG = True`, in my dev environment), I frequently (but not always...) get the following JavaScript error (`toolbar.js`:227):

[image: Uncaught TypeError: djDebug.querySelector is not a function at Object.hide_panels (toolbar.js:227) at Object.hide_toolbar (toolbar.js:236) at HTMLDocument.init (toolbar.js:217)]

Because of that, the toolbar does not appear correctly. I am using `Django 3.0` and the `django-debug-toolbar 2.1` (and Chrome 80.0.3987).

Comment: Have you recently run `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the debugger javascript loaded somewhere on your page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}debugtools/jquery.debug.js"></script>
```

from the docs: 
https://pypi.org/project/django-debugtools/

Comment: Thank you for your help, that fixed my issue. However this point doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the official documentation, that's probably why I forgot it... https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/ Have I missed something?

Comment: Oops, I still have the issue actually, sorry but I cannot accept your answer. I thought it was fixed with this new line but actually not. The thing I frequently have the problem but not always. Don't see any logic here...